# How to remove the gap between parent div and list inside

Tags: html, css

I want to remove the gap on the left that is keeping the list separated from the div and stick the list to the left border,

I've tried to set the position of `li` to `absolute` and to `left:0px` but then it just overlaps and loses it's line up.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AMfv2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ul` elements have margins set by default, removing these will remove the offset. you can then remove the positioning from your `ul` once you've reset the margins:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/AMfv2/3/)

```
.footerlinks {
/* remove this bit */
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
/* add this bit */
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: If not wrong default think is specific to margin only not the padding..correct me if I am wrong and also provide any reference or citation to your post

Comment: @Pilot - you're right, its in the default W3C HTML4 spec: https://github.com/sw4/revert.css/blob/master/revert_w3chtml4.css

Comment: Thanks for addressing my comment.. Here is [reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html)

Comment: thanks both of you for taking the time to answer and edit my post. I'll keep them in mind!.